# RecyclerView lateinit property mClickListener has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, kotlin-lateinit

I've found a tutorial on how to implement `onClickListener` to `RecyclerView` but then I couldn't find out why the code doesn't work. The log says that the lateinit property has not been initialized. I am not sure why it said that. How would I be able to solve this?

This is part of the code in MainActivity:

```
 viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val list = ArrayList<test>()
        recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = viewManager
            adapter = ListAdapter(list)
        }
        ListAdapter(list).setOnItemClickListener(object : ListAdapter.ClickListener {
            override fun onClick(pos: Int, aView: View) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"It works :)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
```

Comment: Try replacing `ListAdapter(list).setOnItemClickListener` with `adapter.setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: @Astha It says unresolved reference. I tried that a while ago but it wouldn't work. Thanks for helping me anyways :)

Comment: The declaration of `adapter` was not shown in the code, anyway the problem was clearly due to different reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are setting the listener on a different instance. You should do something like this:

```
recyclerView = ....apply {
    ...
    adapter = ListAdapter(list).apply {
        setOnItemClickListener(...)
    }
}
```

The other posibility is to create a local `val listAdapter`, instantiate it and set the listener and finally, in the `apply` block of a RV, set `adapter = listAdapter`